# Is there a way to know filenames generated with MultiResourceItemWriter?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm writing a spring-batch application with spring-boot support and I'm looking for a way to know  which files were generated by MultiResourceItemWriter. The first solution I have in mind is to have a folder for only the files generated and check the content, but if there is something already implemented on spring-batch would be great! 
The intention is to encrypt and then upload each file to an sftp server.

Answer (score 0):

The file names generated by the `MultiResourceItemWriter` are the combination of the resource name + the suffix created by the `ResourceSuffixCreator`. For example, if you create the writer like the following:

```
MultiResourceItemWriter<String> writer = new MultiResourceItemWriter<>();
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File("data.txt")));
writer.setResourceSuffixCreator(index -> "part" + index);
```

Then the generated files will be `data.txt.part1`, `data.txt.part2`, etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer it will help me to generate files with a custom name, but I'm looking if there is a way to know if for an execution how many files were generated and their names.

Comment: You take the `write.count` from the step execution and divide it by the value of `itemCountLimitPerResource` you set on the writer, the result is the number of generated files. File names will be the resource name suffixed with numbers starting from 1 up to that number, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`MultiResourceItemWriter` doesn't perform write directly but delegate this job to other components.
All those components are [`ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream.html) implementors so you may write a `ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStreamDelegate`, intercept [`setResource()` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream.html#setResource-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-) and store resource into current step execution-context as a collection.
If you want to pass this list of resources to next steps you may use an [`ExecutionContextPromotionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ExecutionContextPromotionListener.html).

Comment: How can you get the reference to the ExecutionContext in ResourceAwareItemWriterItemStream ?